# Pushing Spark Streaming RDDs to Neo4j -Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j, apache-spark, spark-streaming, anormcypher

I need to establish a connection from Spark Streaming to Neo4j graph database.The RDDs are of type((is,I),(am,Hello)(sam,happy)....). I need to establish a edge between each pair of words in Neo4j.

In Spark Streaming documentation I found

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}

to the push to the data to an external database.
```

I am doing this in Scala. I am little confused about how to go about? I found AnormCypher and Neo4jScala wrapper. Can I use these to get work done? If so, how can I do that? If not, all there any better alternatives?

Thank you all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an experiment with [AnormCypher](http://AnormCypher.org)

Like this:

```
implicit val connection = Neo4jREST.setServer("localhost", 7474, "/db/data/")
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val logData = sc.textFile(FILE, 4).cache()
val count = logData
  .flatMap( _.split(" "))
  .map( w =>
    Cypher("CREATE(:Word {text:{text}})")
      .on( "text" -> w ).execute()
   ).filter( _ ).count()
```

Neo4j 2.2.x has great concurrent write performance that you can use from Spark. So the more concurrent threads you can have to write to Neo4j the better. If you can batch statements in batches of 100 to 1000 each per request then even better.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I am able to push RDD to neo4j to create nodes. I am kind of struck on creating relationships between nodes using AnormCypher. I have gone through the documentation of AnormCypher, but I found nothing on how to create relationships. My code is like - val sampleData = sc.parallelize(List("pandas","i like pandas","most pandas live in china"))
 sampleData.flatMap( _.split(" "))
   .map( w =>
     Cypher("CREATE(:Word {text:{text}})")
       .on( "text" -> w ).execute()
    ).collect()  - if I want to create a realtionship between "panda" and "china" how should I approach that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MazeRunner (http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/11/using-apache-spark-and-neo4j-for-big.html) as it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. I already looked into it, but It only deals with pushing graph processing jobs from Neo4j to Spark-GraphX. What I need is to push RDDs into Neo4j.